# How to use WSL2 python interpreter for spyder autocompletion?

Tags: python, autocomplete, spyder, wsl-2

I am using spyder IDE and python on WSL2 (Windows11). Everything works fine except autocompletion. Spyder uses local python interpreter for autocompletion. I can only get autocompletion for modules which I have on windows. I use RAPIDS in an evironment in WSL2 and do not have these packages on windows.(The same env I get spyder kernel from)

Is there any solution for getting autocompletion for modules in WSL2?

I tried VS code in same situation and it provides autocompletions very well. But I'm not comfortable with notebooks. I even installed spyder on WSL2 and used the GUI but apt-get only provides spyder 3 and it's buggy.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You can try to install Spyder in the same environment where you installed RAPIDS in WSL2 using pip. The package you get with apt-get is probably too outdated and doesn't give you proper completions.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thanks for your response. I tried to install spyder with pip in my conda env. I got this error after calling spyder: ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2: undefined symbol: krb5_ser_context_init, version krb5_3_MIT

Comment: maybe it relates to the error I got while I was installing spyder with pip: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
dask-cudf 22.2.0 requires cupy-cuda115, which is not installed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you had a conda environment in WSL2. So, please use `conda` to install Spyder.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I tried that too. After taking a lot of time it got installed but I get this error after calling spyder in terminal: ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2: undefined symbol: krb5_ser_context_init, version krb5_3_MIT

Comment: Ok, then you need to find what Ubuntu package provides that library and install it with apt-get. For that, you need to go to https://packages.ubuntu.com